# Create a crossplatform home page Widget from an existing xamarin.form PCL

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have a xamarin.forms PCL with Xamarin.Droid and Xamarin.iOS project (for some specific implementation, called with DependencyService).

I have to create a Home Page Widget using my application data (database, current status etc..) Is it possible to integrate a  Home page Widget directly inside my Xamarin.forms PCL project? 
Do I have to create 2 different Widget for Xamarin.Droid & Xamarin.iOS?
What are the best practice with an application linked to a Widget?

What is the best way to deal with this kind of  application?

Comment: I'm afraid is not possible create a widget consuming pcl project. [On the specific platform, it is](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/SimpleWidget/).